# Reduce Cyclomatic Complexity of Switch Statement - Sonar

Tags: java, switch-statement, sonarqube, cyclomatic-complexity

I want to reduce cyclomatic complexity of my switch case 
my code is :

```
public String getCalenderName() {
        switch (type) {
    case COUNTRY:
        return country == null ? name : country.getName() + HOLIDAY_CALENDAR;
    case CCP:
        return ccp == null ? name : ccp.getName() + " CCP" + HOLIDAY_CALENDAR;
    case EXCHANGE:
        return exchange == null ? name : exchange.getName() + HOLIDAY_CALENDAR;
    case TENANT:
        return tenant == null ? name : tenant.getName() + HOLIDAY_CALENDAR;
    default:
        return name;
    }
}
```

This code blocks complexity is 16 and want to reduce it to 10.
country, ccp, exchange and tenant are my diffrent objects. Based on type I will call their respective method.

Comment: "this codes complexity is 16 and want to reduce it to 10" Why not reduce it to 9? or 8? Or 11? Why is 16 problematic?

Comment: According to my sonar rules i want it below 10, it will be great if we can reduce it further. @AndyTurner

Comment: @AmarMagar did you forget to add break statements in each case or its intentional? I am not sure whether adding break statements will help in reducing cyclomatic complexity.

Comment: @Krishna Kuntala There is no need for a `break` statement since in every case he is returning something.

Answer (score 12):

I believe it is a `Sonar` warning. I think `Sonar` warnings are not must-do-rules, but just guides. Your code block is `READABLE` and `MAINTAINABLE` as it is. It is already simple, but if you really want to change it you can try those two approaches below, and see if complexity becomes lower:

Note: I don't have compiler with me now so there can be errors, sorry about that in advance.

First approach:

```
Map<String, String> multipliers = new HashMap<String, Float>();
    map.put("country", country);
    map.put("exchange", exchange);
    map.put("ccp", ccp);
    map.put("tenant", tenant);
```

Then we can just use the map to grab the right element

```
    return map.get(type) == null ? name : map.get(type).getName() + HOLIDAY_CALENDAR;
```

2nd approach:

All your objects have same method, so you can add an `Interface` with `getName()` method in it and change your method signature like:

```
getCalendarName(YourInterface yourObject){
    return yourObject == null ? name : yourObject.getName() + HOLIDAY_CALENDAR;
}
```

Comment: tried first approach already, but not able to call getName on map value

Comment: Use second approach then, introduce a new Interface with a getName() method in it. You should use benefits of polymorphism if you have a common behaviour/method.

Answer (score 4):

If your first aim is only to reduce the cyclomatic complexity, you should create methods for each way of getting the name, like following.

```
 public String getCalenderName() {
    switch (type) {
    case COUNTRY:
        return getCountryName();
    case CCP:
        return getCcpName();
    case EXCHANGE:
        return getExchangeName();
    case TENANT:
        return getTenantName();
    default:
        return name;
    }
}

private String getCountryName() {
    return country == null ? name : country.getName() + HOLIDAY_CALENDAR;
}

private String getCcpName() {
    return ccp == null ? name : ccp.getName() + " CCP" + HOLIDAY_CALENDAR;
}

private String getExchangeName() {
    return exchange == null ? name : getName.toString() + HOLIDAY_CALENDAR;
}

private String getTenantName() {
    return tenant == null ? name : getName.toString() + HOLIDAY_CALENDAR;
}
```

---

Note in your specific example, I suppose that you have 1 class that gather (at least) 4 quite similar behaviours. A refactoring would certainly make more sense, in order to have for example one base implementation (abstract or not), and 4 other inherited classes.

Comment: Of course, add javadoc if you do not want sonar to complain ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think you can lower the complexity just by making sure that something else is fixed in your code.

Take the case:

```
case COUNTRY:
  return country == null ? name : country.getName() + HOLIDAY_CALENDAR;
```

This implies that if the calender type is `COUNTRY`, the country the calender is associated with could be `null`. This is something you should prevent by design because I can't see a reason why this could be a valid situation. Why would you have a country calender without a country?

So make sure that there is a non-null object associated with the calender as soon as you assign a `type` to it. In this way your cases will be like

```
case COUNTRY:
  return country.getName() + HOLIDAY_CALENDAR;
```

which lowers your cyclomatic complexity to 5.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, do not use return statement in switch statement. Apply that logic after the switch statement using a variable.
Create a method for checking the null value and call that method from switch then you will able to reduce the Cyclomatic Complexity

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all the null comparisons and check it prior to switch case. In that case complexity will reduce by 4 or may be more.

Answer (score 0):

If your objects: country, cpp, exchange and tenant share the same interface e.g. ObjectWithGetName you could refactor your code as following:

```
  public String getCalenderName() {
    ObjectWithGetNameMethod calendarType = null;
    switch (type) {
        case COUNTRY:
           calendarType = country;
           break;
        case CCP:
           calendarType = cpp;
           break;
        case EXCHANGE:
           calendarType = exchange;
           break;
        case TENANT:
           calendarType = tenant;
           break;
        default:
           calendarType = null;
    }
    return (calendarType != null ? (calendarType.getName() + HOLIDAY_CALENDAR) : name);
  }
```

Also I think it will be nice to move switch to separate method since it looks like something witch will be used in many different places.

Comment: this solution is not working because country, ccp, exchange and tenant are different entities. so at the time of calling getName method i must use their respective object to call method.

Answer (score -4):

```
public String getName() {
    if (type == null) {
        return name;
    }
    if (type == BusinessCalendarType.COUNTRY) {
        return country == null ? name : country.getName() + HOLIDAY_CALENDAR;
    } else if (type == BusinessCalendarType.CCP) {
        return ccp == null ? name : ccp.getName() + " CCP" + HOLIDAY_CALENDAR;
    } else if (type == BusinessCalendarType.EXCHANGE) {
        return exchange == null ? name : exchange.getName() + HOLIDAY_CALENDAR;
    } else if (type == BusinessCalendarType.TENANT)  {
        return tenant == null ? name : tenant.getName() + HOLIDAY_CALENDAR;
    } else {
        return name;
    }
}
```

this worked for me

Comment: This is functionally wrong. Default from the swicht statement does not corresponds to type==null

Comment: actually type is a Enum and will definitely return one of those 4 values or null only. In my question i have written default statement that is because of the sonar warning. Anyways you are right. I have changed this answer as per your suggestion.

Comment: You just made a relatively (humanly) readable function much harder to read to comply to a _warning_ rule in sonar...